# certificatePinner in retrofit android

Tags: android, ssl, retrofit

i am using retrofit CertificatePinner in android for ssl security concepts. everything is ok, but i have a problem with it that when certificate is changed in ca, CertificatePinner not work for old versions of android because of changing the sha256 or certificate pinner.
for fixing this problem i release a new version for users, and it forces all old user to update the app.
could everyone please tell me, what should i do?
problem is in certificate center for changing certificate every year or is in CertificatePinner in retrofit android.
please help me.

```
public static OkHttpClient getOkHttpClient() {
    CertificatePinner certificatePinner = new CertificatePinner.Builder()
    .add("boom-gard.com", "sha256/YMbwS24oad9JvpmgNSfpdwpBkVZthOzKzl/cSuAF4lI=")
    .build();

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient();
    okHttpClient = okHttpClient.newBuilder()
    .certificatePinner(certificatePinner)
    .connectTimeout(500 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .readTimeout(   500 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .writeTimeout(  500 , TimeUnit.SECONDS)
    .build();

    return okHttpClient;
}
```

Comment: i do have the same problem. Have you found a solution?

Comment: No, i haven't found an appropriate solution, but i think we can not use certificate pinner too, i tested the man in the middle attack by capturing data in android without certificate pinner, it is secured. because i haven't see any data of my app. i think certificate pinner is a additional security. i haven't found a good solution for that yet.

Comment: is it good idea to get public key from server before certificate pinner?